# Click event not fire in highcharts tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using Highchart Library. I create a tooltip via formatter function callback and insert a link inside tooltip.

```
 config.tooltip.formatter = function(){
                    //console.log(this)
                    var tooltipHTML = "<b>✔ " + this.y + "% - " + this.key + "</b>";
                    var userImg = $('.user-picture').html();
                    if (userImg) {
                        tooltipHTML += "<div class='user-avatar-comment'>";
                        tooltipHTML += userImg;
                        tooltipHTML += "</div>";
                    }
                    tooltipHTML += "<div class='comment_filter'><a class='comments_buble' href='#' data-series='" + this.point.index + "'>Comment</a></div>";

                    return tooltipHTML;
                }
```

Now i want to call ajax on click but click event not firing.

```
jQuery('.comments_buble').on('click', function(e) {
//ajax call here
})
```

Here is Code

http://jsfiddle.net/vxnq3578/3/

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Here is code http://jsfiddle.net/vxnq3578/3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tooltips are dynamically appended to the DOM after the page is loaded, so you need to use a delegated event handler:

```
$(document).on('click', '.comments_buble', function(e) {
    // ajax call here
})
```

Comment: #Rory McCrossan I also try that but no luck :-(

Comment: @MuhammadHafeez this answer actually works. Here is the jsfiddle with the code suggested by Rory McCrossan: http://jsfiddle.net/quvaepad/3/

Comment: It was library problem. Highcharts JS v4.0.4 don't allow click event. I just updated the library and it's working fine now.

down vote
ghcharts JS v4.0.4 don't allow click event. I just updated the library and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

```
=> by default all events are reset on container
=> events are triggered from the one level not bubbled
=> tooltip is created "on the fly", so your jQuery has reference to object which does not exist.
=> mixing SVG / HTML elements does not allow you to use CSS pointer-events properly.
```

so you could allow them through tooltip.style
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4q9kga7e/1/

Comment: Nice, this resolved my issue, thanks.