# Highcharts - Unable to call onclick function on label which created in formatter

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I have created Highchart and added custom xAxis labels on it. The custom labels are hyperlinked and need to handle onclick event on it. Please check the below code of Highchart creation.

Formatter code ->

```
labels: {  
      enabled: true,        
      formatter: function() {
        var txn = JSON.parse(this.value);            
        if (!txn || !txn.txnType) {
          return this.value;
        }
        var mvmtLink = '<a classname="x_axis_mvmt_no" >' + txn.no + '</a>';
        return mvmtLink;
      },
      useHTML: true,
    },
```

Whole Code ->

```
Highcharts.AST.allowedAttributes.push('onclick', 'classname');
this.assetsByDelay = {
  title: {
    text: null,
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  chart: {
    styledMode: true,
    className: 'assets-by-delay-chart',
    marginRight: 100,
    labels: {
      useHTML: true,
    },
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      states: {
        hover: {
          enabled: false,
        },
      },
      zones: [{
        className: 'default',
      }],
    },
    bar: {
      pointWidth: 2,
    },
    scatter: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        crop: false,
        x: 40,
        y: 10,
        overflow: 'none',
        formatter: function() {
          return this.point.options.visibleValue - shift;
        },
      },

    },
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false,
  },

  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    title: {
      text: Labels.get('Meta.RTTEP.Movements'),
    },
    labels: {  
      enabled: true,        
      formatter: function() {
        var txn = JSON.parse(this.value);            
        if (!txn || !txn.txnType) {
          return this.value;
        }
        var mvmtLink = '<a classname="x_axis_mvmt_no" >' + txn.no + '</a>';
        return mvmtLink;
      },
      useHTML: true,
    },
    min: 0,
    max: 9,
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    scrollbar: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    tickLength: 0,
  },

  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: Labels.get('meta.label.RTTEP.RemainingDays'),
      align: 'high',
    },
    tickInterval: 10,
    gridLineColor: 'transparent',
    allowDecimals: false,
    labels: {
      //step: 1,
      enabled: true,
      useHTML: true,
    },
    plotLines: [{
      className: 'zero-percent-line',
      value: shift,
    }],
  },
  labels: {
    useHTML: true,
  },          
  series: [{
    type: 'bar',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [],
    showInLegend: false,
    useHTML: true,
  },
  {
    type: 'scatter',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [],
    showInLegend: false,
    keys: ['movement', 'y', 'type', 'visibleValue'],
    marker: {
      symbol: 'this property required to be set',
      fontAwesomeConfig: {
        symbol: 'text:\uf0d1',
        customizeFn: function(svgElem, x, y, w, h, options) {
          return svgElem.attr({
            translateY: h - 23,
            translateX: 0,
            rotate: 90,
          })
            .css({
              fontFamily: '"Font Awesome 5 Free"',
              fontSize: '14px',
              'font-weight': 900,
            });
        },
      },
    },
  }],

};
```

As shown, I have added formatter for xAxis labels and shown text as hyperlink but unable to achieve onclick event on it. I tried the below solutions but they didn't work -

1. Added onclick event in anchor tag.

[image]

2. Added click event on labels of x-axis but it is not working on click of custom label, it works after clicking on the axis of the chart. Hence unable to achieve the target.
3. Added load event on chart so can access the axis labels but it didn't work.
4. Used the below solution but formatter gets called at last every time so this soution is also not working.
   [Click event not fire in highcharts tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31669246/click-event-not-fire-in-highcharts-tooltip)

Can someone please help to provide the solution to register and call onclick event on custom axis labels of Highcharts.

```
 if (document.getElementsByClassName('.x_axis_mvmt_no').length > 0) {
            document.getElementsByClassName('.x_axis_mvmt_no').click(function () {
              console.log(this);
            });
          }
```

Comment: [Does this answer solve your problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62229151/react-highcharts-unable-to-call-function-from-data-label-onclick)

Comment: `click()` performs a click on the element programmatically, the callback you pass in is ignored: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

Comment: Also, in React, we don't interact with the DOM directly with methods like `document.getElementByClassName()`. Instead, we use props to pass values to components and the render lifecycle. I suggest you study a react tutorial to learn more about this.

Comment: @NIKUNJPATEL that solution is having an error, after resolving that error looks like onclick is not working as there is nothing get printed in the console

Comment: @NIKUNJPATEL Thanks for looking for a question that already answers this question. I think the one you linked doesn't have a correct answer, though.

Comment: @Learner Are you using reactjs or not? You tagged your question with reactjs and react-highcharts, but your code is vanilla javascript. If you are using react, I recommend you check out the examples in the highcharts-react documentation: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes, this is React JS code, only in formatter or onclick handler you can see vanilla JS code due to facing few issues while adding implementation in React but it is not working anyway. Thanks for the reference, I will check it an d find out if it works for me.

Comment: Hi @Learner, Please check this simple live example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6tqms7w4/ - as you can see, both ways (inline and through class name) of adding events work correctly. Please adapt the example to show the problem.

Comment: @ppotaczek Please post an answer below with code snippets and a link to your js fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to add `classname` to allowed AST attributes. The `class` attribute is allowed by default.

```
Highcharts.AST.allowedAttributes.push('onclick');
```

---

Events can be added in the both suggested ways. Thorough inline attribute:

```
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    labels: {
      useHTML: true,
      formatter: function() {
        return this.value + ' <a onclick="..." class="x_axis_mvmt_no">Link</a>'
      }
    }
  }
```

---

And by using class name:

```
const labels = document.getElementsByClassName('x_axis_mvmt_no');

[...labels].forEach(label => {
  label.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('label clicked');
  });
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6tqms7w4/